# Failed to return value from Postgres store procedure in Vertx3

Tags: java, postgresql-9.1, vertx3

I can't seems to get value returned from postgres db...any idea how to fix this ?

```
JsonArray outParam = new JsonArray().add("integer");

connection.callWithParams(spAddUser, params, outParam, response -> {

    if (response.succeeded()) {
        ResultSet result = response.result();
    ...
```

I got this error saying:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: No function outputs were registered.
at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.checkIndex(PgStatement.java:2208)
at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.checkIndex(PgStatement.java:2191)
at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.getObject(PgStatement.java:2088)
at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyCallableStatement.getObject(NewProxyCallableStatement.java:172)
at io.vertx.ext.jdbc.impl.actions.JDBCCallable.convertOutputs(JDBCCallable.java:83)
at io.vertx.ext.jdbc.impl.actions.JDBCCallable.execute(JDBCCallable.java:59)
at io.vertx.ext.jdbc.impl.actions.JDBCCallable.execute(JDBCCallable.java:33)
at io.vertx.ext.jdbc.impl.actions.AbstractJDBCAction.handle(AbstractJDBCAction.java:48)
```

Here is my sample store procedure:

```
create or replace function addUser(_acid int, _slno int, _dob date)
returns int as $$

    insert into users (acid,slno,dob)
    values (_acid, _slno, _dob)
    returning uid;
$$ language sql;
```

Answer (score 1):

I found out I don't have to pass in the output params if am not using IN/OUT in my stored procedure. So setting output parameter to `null` fixes the problem.

```
connection.callWithParams(spAddUser, params, null, response -> {

if (response.succeeded()) {
    ResultSet result = response.result();
...
```